# TFS 2015 Copy and Publish Build Artifacts without subdirectories

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have created a Copy and Publish Build Artifacts build step in TFS 2015 with the following parameters:

- Copy Root: $(build.sourcesdirectory)\bin\Installers
- Contents: **

The according to https://www.visualstudio.com/pl-pl/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts it should not copy the subdirecttories but unfortunately it does it!

How to copy and publish build artifacts whitout subfolders?

Comment: Did you try with *.*?

Comment: Yes I did - the same effect. But I will retry

Comment: @Pellared, I have submitted a feedback for this issue at website below, you can vote it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3107122

Answer (score 1):

Please add the suffix of the files after **, then you won't get the subdirectories. For example, in the following setting, you'll only get .txt and .dll files under `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\bin\Installers`, but you won't get .txt and .dll files in any sub folders under `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\bin\Installers`:

[image]

Comment: I think it should be **\\*.txt and not **.txt.

Comment: @TheShooter, If use **\ *, then you'll get .txt files in the root folder and all files in all sub-folders, but customer only wants to get .txt files in the root folder without sub-folders. So **.txt is enough.

Comment: @Pellared, then you can use **. * as Eddie mentioned. :-)

Comment: `*.*` works not ideally because it copies also folders which have a dot `.` in the folder name

Answer (score 0):

You can use `**.*` instead of `**`.

Comment: @Pellared Yes, I tested it at my side. What's the result you get with it?

Comment: Copies nothing... While `*.*` copies all files and folders which have a dot. Have you tested it on VSO or on on premises TFS 2015?